# QApplication segmentation fault

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, qt4.8

I get a crash when try to create a `QApplication` object. This is my code:

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    return app.exec();
}
```

I am using Qt version 4.8.4 and the MinGW compiler. My application crashes when running `QCoreApplicationPrivate::processCommandLineArguments` method. Can anybody tell how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you giving it any particular command line arguments that cause a problem, or does it always happen?

Comment: No, I am not. This problem takes place whenever I executing my application. Nemanja Boric was absolutely right, it is because Qt library version and mingw gcc version doesn't match. I solve this problem compiling Qt library by my own, as it is quite difficult to find an outdated version of mingw.

Comment: @Zimka: Yes there is chaos with mingw version numbering. Currently I am testing third version of it having the problem you described (beside others).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, this error is caused by binary incompatibility of Qt binaries and your compiler.

From [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/MinGW):

> There are binary installers targetting MinGW for both Qt 4 and Qt 5.
>   The Qt 4 ones are built with aMinGW.org toolchain using gcc 4.4. The
>   Qt 5 ones are based on a MinGW-builds toolchain [sourceforge.net]
>   using gcc 4.7.2. The Qt 5 installer also ships the toolchain itself.

If you are using gcc 4.7 (I think this is the default version with the latest MinGW), you can't compile (well, you can, but [it will not work](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/19806)) with Qt 4 precompiled binaries.

So, either downgrade your gcc to 4.4 version, or upgrade Qt to latest (Qt 5) version.