# QApplication Program Execution Segmentation

Tags: c++, qt

Could anybodyy help me with this problem? I am trying to run an application using the cmakefiles. on the main file of my program I get a segmentation fault when the program gets to the line of code to execute the QAppication. Here is the fragment code below:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
bool viewing;
parse_command_line( argc, argv );

#ifdef _GRAPHICS_

  glutInit(&argc, argv);   // note the code runs correctly when this line is excluded and the glutInit was initialized in another class named Viewer (See class Viewer instantiated below), however for my specific application I need to initialize the glutInit in the main program
#endif

 if( viewing )
        {
#ifdef _GRAPHICS_
      QApplication application(argc, argv);
      Viewer    *viewer = new Viewer( 0, exp, argc, argv );
      Interface *render = new Interface( 0, exp, viewer );
      render->show();
      return application.exec(); //this line causes the segmentation fault
      delete viewer;
      delete render;
#endif
        }


}
```

Comment: If you reduce main to only `glutInit(&argc, argv);` does it still crash?

Comment: What about this similar problem [QApplication segmentation fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685425/qapplication-segmentation-fault?rq=1)?

Comment: Lines after `return` will never executed!

Answer (score 0):

When `glutInit` is called inside `Viewer`, `application` and `viewer` receive all the command line arguments. When you call it before, like you do, `glutInit` will eat all the parameters it understands, so the other objects might miss some arguments.

Possible solutions: do the `glutInit` (after application creation), or make a copy of argc/argv.